# TypeError: Cannot read property 'validate' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation

I am trying to validate my registration form but I'm getting this error and I can't solve it. my form submit button goes to `handleRegistration` which should validate the form first then submit. I was trying to follow the example in this link https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/password-and-confirm-password-validation-in-reactexample.html

```js
handleRegistration(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (this.validate()) {
    this.toggleModal();
    console.log(this.state);
    let input = {};
    input["name"] = "";
    input["email"] = "";
    input["password"] = "";
    input["confirmPassword"] = "";
    input["age"] = "";
    input["gender"] = "";
    this.setState({
      input: input
    });
    console.log(this.state)
    alert('Demo Form is submited');
  }
}

validate() {
  let input = this.state.input;
  let errors = {};
  let isValid = true;

  if (!input["fullname"]) {
    isValid = false;
    errors["fullname"] = "Please enter your name.";
  }

  if (!input["email"]) {
    isValid = false;
    errors["email"] = "Please enter your email Address.";
  }

  if (typeof input["email"] !== "undefined") {

    var pattern = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
    if (!pattern.test(input["email"])) {
      isValid = false;
      errors["email"] = "Please enter valid email address.";
    }
  }

  if (!input["password"]) {
    isValid = false;
    errors["password"] = "Please enter your password.";
  }

  if (!input["confirmPassword"]) {
    isValid = false;
    errors["confirmPassword"] = "Please confirm your password.";
  }

  if (!input["age"]) {
    isValid = false;
    errors["age"] = "Please Enter your age.";
  }

  if (typeof input["password"] !== "undefined" && typeof input["confirmPassword"] !== "undefined") {

    if (input["password"] != input["confirmPassword"]) {
      isValid = false;
      errors["password"] = "Passwords don't match.";
    }
  }

  this.setState({
    errors: errors
  });

  return isValid;
}

handleChange(event) {
  let input = this.state.input;
  input[event.target.name] = event.target.value;

  this.setState({
    input
  });
}
```

I am initalizing my input and errors objects in my state here

```js
this.state = {
  isNavOpen: false,
  isModalOpen: false,
  isRegistrationModalOpen: false,
  input: {},
  errors: {}
}
```

and my registration form is structured like that

```html
<Form onSubmit={this.handleRegistration}>
  <FormGroup>
    <Input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" value={this.state.input.name} onChange={this.handleChange}></Input>
    <div className="text-danger">{this.state.errors.name}</div>
  </FormGroup>
  ....
</Form>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem**

```html
<Form onSubmit={this.handleRegistration}>
```

`this.handleRegistration` wasn't bound to the class (component) therefor `this` doesn't refer to the class instance.

**The solution**

Declare the method as arrow function. This way it will be the instance method but not on the prototype so `this` will refer to the instance.

```
handleRegistration(event) {
```

to

```
handleRegistration = (event) => {
```

More info: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#class-properties-stage-3-proposal.

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I forgot binding it. Thanks